# How to display a jsp with over 64k bytes

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to dispaly a jsp page (generated at runtime) in my app and when I choose the button on my main page to dispaly the results of an operation that generates the jsp, I get the following error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [38] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\Tom\Programming IDEs\workspace-eclipse-java-web\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\work\Catalina\localhost\LAEWeb\org\apache\jsp\WEB_002dINF\test_jsp.java]
The code of method _jspService(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit
```

How do you display jsp pages with over 64k of data? The jsp has numbers data with over 16,800 lines with five numbers per line.

Comment: What container are you using? See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7495985/1391249) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5484253/1391249).

Comment: In the normal circumstances the JSP rarely needs to exceed the limit. What is the source code it looks like?

Comment: divide your jsp page with more than one page and use jsp include directive.it will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if possible then divide your jsp page with more than one page and use jsp include directive.it will work.

Comment: I used the <jsp:include...> for dynamic content and it worked. Thanks. It took a while streamlining the code to print multiple jsp pages, but I finally got it. If anyone would like to see the code, leave a comment and I'll post it. By the way, I'm using eclipse with tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for above question is

Locate the file [Tomcat_Home]/conf/web.xml and search the file for 'JspServlet'. This should return an xml node of  containing some  values. You will need to add an additional  the same as the below.

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>mappedfile</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</init-param>
```