# JSTL not working while adding some parmaters in web.xml

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, jstl

JSTL not working after adding following lines to web.xml

```
    <servlet>
     <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param> 
        <param-name>mappedfile</param-name>
         <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
```

It shows the following exception while moving to the jsp where jstl is included.

> **org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application**
>   Although the jstl is at the class path.
>   Also I dont want to remove the changes in web.xml

Comment: Please check the version of `JSTL` used, how are you injecting `Jstl`, through  `POM`, What is the import for `jstl` you have used inside `jsp` page

Comment: Did you edit it in Tomcat's own web.xml, or did you copy that in your webapp's web.xml?

Comment: @ankur-singhal JSTL version is proper as prior to injecting the code in web.xml The jsp is working properly

Comment: @BalusC it is part of my webapp's web.xml and I am using Jboss 5.1.0 Server not Tomcat

Comment: You're not supposed to duplicate server's own JSP servlet in webapp's `web.xml`. This is recipe for trouble (although I can't confirm if broken JSTL is indeed one of the consequences, I haven't seen this kind of symptom yet). You should reconfigure it in JBoss itself. Try following the instructions described here: http://www.techstacks.com/howto/remove-the-x-powered-by-header-in-jboss.html

Comment: @BalusC the above parameters are added because of the following reason-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495985/byte-limit-exceed-problem-when-reloading-a-jsp-page/26647081#26647081

One of my jsp file is exceeding the limit. I reffered above link for this.

Comment: The xpoweredby header part is not relevant, just the way how you edit JBoss default JSP servlet is relevant. Follow the same guideline for editing any of JBoss default JSP servlet configuration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83745/discussion-between-ankit-duggal-and-balusc).

Comment: I have removed xpoweredBy and fork init param but I require mapped file as false because one of my jsp is exceeding the limit.

Comment: You are really not understanding me? I will say this once more and for the last time: You're not supposed to duplicate server's own JSP servlet in webapp's `web.xml`. This is recipe for trouble. You should reconfigure it in JBoss itself.