# jspService(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I am facing problem when i use the web application in tomcat 7.

I tried configuring tomcat as below (in $CATALINA_HOME/conf/web.xml), could not help.

```
   <init-param> 
        <param-name>mappedfile</param-name>
         <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

Error details

```
Dec 19, 2014 7:45:44 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [myapp] in context with path [/myapp] threw     
exception [Unable to compile class for JSP:

Stacktrace:] with root cause
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:

An error occurred at line: [135] in the generated java file: [/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/work/Catalina/localhost/myapp/org/apache/jsp/WEB_002dINF/jsp/myaccount/myapp_jsp.java]
The code of method _jspService(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit

Stacktrace:
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: A java class has a size limit of 64k - you have a seriously long JSP or a lot of imports?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484253/jspservice-is-exceeding-the-65535-bytes-limit

This Question seems fits your question well.