# component inclusion failed in aem

Tags: jsp, aem

i am exposing freemarker template from aem to backend service to send mails.since the file is too big i am seeing the following error.
please suggest me the approach to resolve the issue.

Error Message:

> org.apache.sl
>   ing.api.scripting.ScriptEvaluationException:
>   org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.JasperException:  Unable to
>   compile class for JSP:  An error occurred at line: 80 in the generated
>   java file The code of method 
>   _jspService(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and include details of what you have tried. Consider including a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This isn't specific to AEM. Your script is simply too complex and it compiles to a class that's too long. Please see [_jspService is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484253/jspservice-is-exceeding-the-65535-bytes-limit) for a possible solution.