# Spring boot _jspService is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit

Tags: jsp, spring-boot, web.xml, embedded-tomcat-8

I'm getting the following error

> _jspService(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit

I know that with Apache Tomcat the following tag in tomcat's web.xml fixes the issue

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
    ...
    <init-param>
        <param-name>mappedfile</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    ...
</servlet>
```

But I'm using **embedded tomcat** with **Spring Boot**.
So there is no web.xml
I'm not sure were this configuration will go or if there is another workaround.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484253/jspservice-is-exceeding-the-65535-bytes-limit check this out

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a late answer but I just stumbled upon same issue with jsp, spring boot and embedded tomcat and below is the simple solution that saved my day.

Add below property in spring boot **"application.properties"** file and restart the server, it should resolve the problem -

```
server.servlet.jsp.init-parameters.mappedfile=false
```

Answer (score 1):

Customize JspServlet initparameter **mappedfile** to **false** using `WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory>`.

sample code is below to override customize method of **WebServerFactoryCustomizer**

```
public void customise(TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory) {
     factory.getJsp().setInitParameters(..);
}
```

ideally, you can minimize generated servlet size by avoiding below statement in your JSP

```
<%@ include file="display.jsp" %>
```

and by using below

```
<jsp:include page="display.jsp" />
```