# Configuration of Eclipse/Jetty to solve the issue: the code of method is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit

Tags: eclipse, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I am developing a Java site in Eclipse. The site depends on JSP files and servlets, and I use a plugin (Eclipse Jetty 5.0.0) to run the site within Eclipse during development. I got this exception when loading a page in the browser:

```
XXXXX_jsp.java]<|The code of method _jspService(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit
```

I will eventually run this site on Tomcat, and I am able to solve this issue in Tomcat by adding the following to JspServlet within tomcat_install/conf/web.xml:

```
   <init-param>
        <param-name>mappedfile</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

However, I did quite search and was unable to find a similar configuration solution to make it work in Eclipse/Jetty. I could break the method into a few smaller ones, but I want to avoid it. Hope to use a configuration (not code change) to solve this issue.

Comment: There's no such thing as "Eclipse Jetty 5.0.0" btw (First version at Eclipse was 7.0.0)

Comment: This has been answered before at https://stackoverflow.com/a/58450789/775715

Comment: When you upgrade Tomcat you'll hit this problem again.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt if you search the Eclipse market, you will find this plugin. Regarding Tomcat, I will address it as I said in the post. Thanks for chiming in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JettyJspServlet` supports the same init-params as Tomcat's `JspServlet`.

The `mappedfile` init-param is there (just set it to something invalid like "foo" and watch the error message pop out "*Warning: Invalid value for the initParam mappedFile. Will use the default value of "false"*")

You'll need to reference the existing JSP servlet and add those init-parameters to your `WEB-INF/web.xml`.

```xml
<servlet id="jsp">
  <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>mappedfile</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Or create a new `webdefault.xml` with this parameter and have your webapp use it with the XML deployables in `${jetty.base}/webapps/${webappid}.xml`

```xml
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
   <Set name="contextPath">/foo</Set>
   <Set name="war"><Property name="jetty.webapps"/>/foobar.war</Set>
   <Set name="defaultsDescriptor"><Property name="jetty.base"/>/etc/mywebdefault.xml</Set>
</Configure>
```

**The "mappedfile" init-param:**

It appears to switch from generating normal print statements in the intermediate *.java file to 1 liner print statements.
This means you are at the razors edge of JavaC support in your JSP file.  There are many hard limits to the size of the *.java file on javac, and your JSP file is tickling those limits now.

Some (but not all) javac limits:

- Static Initializers Size: 65535 bytes max.
- Method or Constructor Length: 65535 bytes max. (the one your JSP file is tripping on)
- Method or Constructor Parameter Length: 255 parameters max.
- Local Variables Size: 65535 bytes max.
- Synthetic Parameters Length: 255 parameters max.
- Array Dimensions: 255 max.

If this init-param works for you, then use it.
But if you need to maintain / edit that JSP file, know that you can almost certainly not add to it (only remove).
You'll likely have to refactor it into smaller pieces with imports in the future.